# How to use Stack Navigator while still showing Bottom Tab Navigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm currently developing an app where there is a Bottom Tab Navigator with 4 pages in it, but there are also other pages outside the tab navigator that the user can access, how can I show these pages to the user while also having the Bottom Tab Navigator at the bottom for quick access to the main pages?

Note: None of the tab navigator pages should be selected while showing the other pages

I tried using the default approach of nesting a stack navigator inside the Bottom Tab Navigator but in this approach I have to duplicate some common pages used throughout the app in each nested stack navigator... Also when any of the pages that aren't in the tab navigator are being displayed none of the icons in the Tab Navigator have to be selected

Any help would be appreciated
Thanks

Comment: Try to look this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69930158/react-native-how-do-i-type-nested-navigators-properly/74910521#74910521

Comment: The answer given above is vague in the sense that it's mainly related to typescript support with nested navigators, if you have an example with code, could you please provide it, thanks

Comment: https://snack.expo.dev/?platform=web try this

Comment: Have you been able to solve this?

Comment: @Lucas No... not yet still using this approach currently: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/nesting-navigators/

Comment: @RohanRajesh, update your code , let us see how you called your code in App.js